# How do you render jwt token using active model serializer for a user when they sign in / sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, jwt, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I am using Rails API and Active model serializers to render custom JSON responses on a user when they sign up / sign in and don't know how to add generated JWT tokens to this so I can retrieve it for further requests using Postman. When I send user sign up information I need to see this token in the response with everything else.

**Configuration**

- **Rails API** only
- **Devise** for user auth
- **jwt gem** for tokens
- **Postman** for API requests

Here is my code:

**User serializer**

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :username, :bio, :avatar, :created_at, :updated_at
end
```

**user model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base


  include ActiveModel::Validations

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
           :trackable

  has_one_attached :avatar

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

  def generate_jwt
    JWT.encode({ id: id,
      exp: 60.days.from_now.to_i },
      Rails.application.credentials.secret_key_base)
  end

end
```

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API

    respond_to :json

    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

    before_action :authenticate_user


      private


      def configure_permitted_parameters
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :username, :bio, :avatar])
        devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name])
      end

      def authenticate_user
        if request.headers['Authorization'].present?
          authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token|
            begin
              jwt_payload = JWT.decode(token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base).first

              @current_user_id = jwt_payload['id']
            rescue JWT::ExpiredSignature, JWT::VerificationError, JWT::DecodeError
              head :unauthorized
            end
          end
        end
      end


      def authenticate_user!(options = {})
        head :unauthorized unless signed_in?
      end

      def current_user
        @current_user ||= super || User.find(@current_user_id)
      end

      def signed_in?
        @current_user_id.present?
      end

    end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


scope :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
     devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: :sessions },
                       path_names: { sign_in: :login }

     resource :user, only: [:show, :update]

     end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have `user` information stored in `@user` instance and the `token` stored in `@token` instance variable.

Since you have not mentioned the routes, I'll assume that you want to create a `user`

```rb
def create
  @user = User.create(user_params)
  if @user.save
    render json: { user: UserSerializer.new(@user), token: @token }, status: :created
  else
    render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: :bad_request  
  end
end

private

def user_params
 # stuff
end
```

Comment: Thank you, @Abeid Ahmed!